# Can't I run driver.refresh () a random number of times?

Tags: python, selenium

Like the title, we want to do a refresh a random number of times.

Can't I run `driver.refresh ()` a random number of times?

```
  ran_list = [1, 4, 5, 2, 7]

        while True:
            previous_url = driver.current_url
            list_of_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table//tr//td[@class='subject left txtBreak']/a")

            for linktext in range(len(list_of_links)):
                rand_idx = randint(0, len(ran_list)-1) 
                random_num = ran_list[rand_idx]
                list_of_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table//tr//td[@class='subject left txtBreak']/a")
                element = list_of_links[linktext]                
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
                time.sleep(3)
                driver.refresh(str(random_num)) #An error occurs at this point.
                time.sleep(3)
                driver.back()
                time.sleep(3)
                .
                .
```

Comment: What libraries are you using? You'll want to look at the documentation for what `driver` is, and what type of argument `refresh` takes - I'm guessing it's not a String.

Comment: @DylanMcNamee using python + selenium. "driver.execute_script (" arguments [0] .click (); ", element)" I'm trying to run refresh a random number (ran_list) on that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to call `refresh` in a loop instead of passing the random int as a parameter.

```
ran_list = [1, 4, 5, 2, 7]

    while True:
        previous_url = driver.current_url
        list_of_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table//tr//td[@class='subject left txtBreak']/a")

        for linktext in range(len(list_of_links)):
            rand_idx = randint(0, len(ran_list)-1) 
            random_num = ran_list[rand_idx]
            list_of_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table//tr//td[@class='subject left txtBreak']/a")
            element = list_of_links[linktext]                
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
            time.sleep(3)

            # Refresh random number of times
            for i in range(random_num):
                driver.refresh()

            time.sleep(3)
            driver.back()
            time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Thank you.
But it doesn't work and stops right away :(

Comment: I updated my answer to use the variables in your existing code. Did you test with this version?

Comment: ok.  for i in range(random_num): <-- Added Colon Works fine.
Thank you again!

Comment: My apologies, must have been a typo! I will update my answer with the colon.

Answer (score 1):

`Driver.navigate.refresh` command:
This is the inbuilt method for performing page refresh operation provided by Selenium web driver. This command is the most commonly used command across test automation for performing a page refresh operation. Refresh command can be used in a simple way as mentioned below.

```
driver.get("http://demo.guru99.com/selenium/guru99home/");
driver.navigate().refresh();
```

Navigation is an interface that is used to perform various browser operations like navigating to the previous page, navigating to next page, page refresh, browser close. Navigation interface methods can be accessed using the `command driver.navigate()`. Refresh method of Navigation interface does not take any arguments or return any values.

Please understand the function before you apply in your code [More](https://www.guru99.com/selenium-refresh-page.html)

Comment: Thank you. Let's understand and apply more.

Comment: this answer refers to the Java bindings...  the question specified Python... driver.navigate() does not even exist in Python bindings.